# How to get all values from a new node being created in hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()

Tags: 8, hooks

Drupal 8.7.2

```
function mymodule_node_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  data_dump($entity->original); //is empty because its a new node, not a node being updated.
  // How to get all values at one time?
  // By values I mean the same value you would get from:
  data_dump($entity->get('title')->value);
  // but from all fields and not just one field at a time.
}
```

I have a custom content type that has 30 custom fields that I need to examine inside this hook.  I'd like to avoid getting the value of each field individually.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a few different ways to get that info, but if the returned format suits your needs then [`EntityInterface::toArray()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3AtoArray/8.7.x), which *Gets an array of all property values*, is probably the most succinct:

```
$field_data = $entity->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [Content Entity Field definitions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/defining-and-using-content-entity-field-definitions)

Sample code:

```
foreach ($entity->getFieldDefinitions() as $field => $definition) {
    $entity->get($field)->getValue()
}
```